# is it possible to show if an payable android app is purchased or not in Google Analytics (API or not)

Tags: android, google-analytics

Is it possible using google analytics to findout if payable apps are payed or just copied ?

Or is there an other way to find out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ir is not a feature in G analytics, but you should be able to use the Google Vendor Authorization API (from Google Play Services) in your app to tell if the app that the user has installed is valid or not (paid vs. not-paid). You can then send that data up and correlate it with your Google Analytics data. IIRC, you can add your own data to the Google Analytics package.